# will_paginate throug Individual Users Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, will-paginate

I would like my users to be able to paginate through their own posts (scheduling emails). Thanks in advance to anyone who can help or steer me in the right direction!

Emails have different categories, Scheduled and Pending. I have two scopes for these in my emails model.

```
email.rb
scope :pending, -> { where(email_pending: true) }

scope :approved, -> { where(email_pending: false) }
```

I'm using devise to organize users. In my Users controller I have users#show action and I'm pulling the user's emails like this.

```
users_controller.rb
def show
    @emails = @user.emails
end
```

Then in my view I list each category of email like this.

```
users#show
<% @user.emails.approved.each do |email| %>
-----Stuff------
<% end %>
Same thing goes for pending.
```

So, to paginate (using will_paginate) I tried.

```
users_controller.rb
@emails = @user.emails.approved.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
```

and in the view I added.

```
users#show
<%= will_paginate @user.emails.approved %>
```

I also tried a few other things, but it was pretty much just guessing and trial and error... nothing worked.

Thanks again for any help! Please let me know if anyone would needs more information from me.

-Kraymer

Comment: please explain the nothing worked.  What error do you get when you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the response Doon. Well, it worked in the sense that when I set the per_page to 5, it displayed the correct number of pages in the nav, but all the posts were listed and if I clicked on page 2, it just showed all the posts still. Additionally, some other thing I tried raised _undefined method `total_pages'_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if in the show method of your users_controller you have

```
@emails = @user.emails.approved.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page:
```

in the view you will need to use the `@emails` that you created

```
<% @emails.each do |email| %>
 ..... 
<% end %> 

<%= will_paginate @emails %>
```

Since by accessing  `@user.emails.approved` you are not looking at paginated version, but the original active relation.

Comment: That's what I though would work too. I tried that, but I still get a full list of my posts. It's odd, because it recognizes how many pages I should have. Eg. I have 7 posts, with per_page set to 3, so the nav show links 1-3, it just doesn't list the correct amount of posts.

Comment: you need to use @emails in your loop as well.  the will_paginate calll just uses that to figure out how many is left, etc.. updated answer to show that.

Comment: Doon, thanks for your help and thanks for explaining what was wrong with my original attempt. It makes sense to me now.

Comment: Sorry Didn't have a chance to finis editing my original reply.Doon, thanks for your help and thanks for explaining what was wrong with my original attempt. It makes sense to me now. I was able to get it working, but by doing so a new problem came to light. Since I'm paginating through Scheduled and Pending posts on the same page(separated by tabs) clicking on one link causes the other category to change as well. I assuming I'll have to attempt some AJAX or JavaScript approach. Do you have any thoughts on this? Does this sounds like the correct direction I should head in? Thanks again!

Comment: how are you changing them from pending to scheduled?  If that isn't via ajax, (and involves a page load)  when you reload the page the DB should already be updated and they will be in the right place. If it is done via ajax,  you could use javascript to move from 1 list/category to the other after the ajax calls is successful, and then once you move pages all should be correct.

Comment: also if this answered you question, you can mark it as answered so that others know it is solved,  if you have new issues, you should open a new question as opposed to comments / edits to an existing one (Welcome to SO)

Comment: Thanks again for your help Doon. Your answer fixed my problem and thanks for also providing a good explanation, it really helped me understand the why. I decided to go an alternate route on the whole AJAX/JavaScript problem, but if decide to revisit I'll open up a new issue.